# replace urls variable value

Tags: php, url, variables

I have the following url

```
/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=292&Itemid=283
```

What I want to do to replace `item_id`'s value with a variable. I have been checking a couple of php functions like `split` and `parse_str`, but I do not know how I to get it to work.

Comment: is this a url you are creating for a link?  or are you inside index.php and trying to work with the passed value in item_id?

Comment: Is this URL in a string, or the current URL (in the address bar)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$url = '/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=292&Itemid=283';

$query = explode('?', $url); // Split the URL on `?` to get the query string
parse_str($query[1], $data); // Parse the query string into an array

echo $data['item_id']; // 292

$newValue = 300;
$data['item_id'] = $newValue; // Replace item_id's value

$url = $query[0].'?'.http_build_query($data); // rebuild URL

echo $url; // '/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=300&Itemid=283";
```

Comment: whoa thats it, this is what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the `str_replace` function. If you have your URL stored in the variable `$url` and the variable you want to replace Itemid stored in `$ItemID`:

```
$url = str_replace("Itemid", $ItemID, $url);
```

Comment: I think he wants to replace the `292` (`item_id`'s value).

Comment: This doesn't replace the value, but the item itself.

Comment: yeah actually I wanted to replace the value, Rockets workaround seems to be perfect.

Comment: ah ok, I should have looked past the blue "Itemid" and realized it was actually the value you wanted to replace. :)

Answer (score 0):

**this is the exact way of doing it **

```
 <?php
    $url = '/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=292&Itemid=283';
    $explodeData =parse_url($url);
    $dataReplace = str_replace('item_id','replacedvariable',$explodeData['query'],$count);
    $changedUrl = $explodeData['path']."?".$dataReplace;
    echo $changedUrl;
    ?>
```